# Facing this error :- TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'?

Tags: python, json, list, function, dictionary

**Query)**  I was trying to plot a graph, using coordinates mentioned in dict_A, but the operation halted showing the error

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'.`

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ast import literal_eval


def any_function():

    with open('contents.txt') as f:
        A               = f.readline()  
        dict_A          = json.loads(A)         # converts to dictionary

        B = dict((literal_eval, i) for i in dict_A.items()) #convert k, v to int

#plotting a simple graph-based on coordinates mentioned in A.

        x = [i[0]  for i in  B.values()]
        y = [i[1]  for i in  B.values()]
        size = 50
        offset = size/100.
        for i, location in enumerate(zip(x,y)):
            plt.annotate(i+1, ( location[0]-offset, location[1]-offset), zorder=10 )  
        
    return {'A':dict_A}
    

any_function()                 #calling the function
```

**This is my data inside the text file (contents.txt)**

```
{"1":"[0,0]", "2":"[5, 0]", "3":"[6,0]","4":"[3,5]"}
```

**Error coming**

```
runfile('D:/python programming/a new program 2021/testing 9 input.py', wdir='D:/python programming/a new program 2021')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\python programming\a new program 2021\testing 9 input.py", line 37, in <module>
    a = any_function()

  File "D:\python programming\a new program 2021\testing 9 input.py", line 32, in any_function
    plt.annotate(i+1, ( location[0]-offset, location[1]-offset), zorder=10 )

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the full traceback, and ideally reduce your code to a [mre]. The error looks like you tried to use a value without converting it to a `float` first, probably from a string in the input JSON; but without the traceback, this is idle speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m not sure what you think this is doing, but it's not what you expect:

```
B = dict((literal_eval, i) for i in dict_A.items()) #convert k, v to int
```

That doesn't convert anything to int.  The inner part of that:

```
(literal_eval, i)
```

will product a tuple that contains the `literal_eval` function object, and the item pairs from your dictionary.  I'm guessing you didn't `print(B)` to see what you were building.  Since all of the items have the same key, what you end up with is this:

```
>>> B = dict((literal_eval, i) for i in t.items()) #convert k, v to int
>>> B
{<function literal_eval at 0x7f531ddcb5e0>: ('4', '[3,5]')}
```

What you actually want is to CALL literal_eval:

```
>>> B = dict((literal_eval(k), literal_eval(v)) for k,v in t.items())
>>> B
{1: [0, 0], 2: [5, 0], 3: [6, 0], 4: [3, 5]}
>>>
```